# Ubuntu 20 - screen freezes from time to time when working with external monitor

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, freeze

My ubuntu laptop is freezing from time to time. It is still running (i.e. music continues to play) but everything freezes. I really do not know what to do here and thought about drivers, heat or the fact that I have a second ssd with windows on the laptop.
What can I do or check to find the reason for that?

```
sudo lshw -class display 
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:147 memory:f1000000-f1ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:e000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: Lexa PRO [Radeon 540/540X/550/550X / RX 540X/550/550X]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: c0
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:149 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f2400000-f243ffff memory:f2440000-f245ffff
```

Answer (score 0):

Drivers look OK, second SSD can't be it, heat is not so very logical (except if it's your gpu), but I personnally think it is sillicon degrade/OC on the main graphics card. If your laptop is still in warrenty, try bringing it back to the computer shop and if you OC, stop OCing. (source, my RX 570 on the bricked OC bios with a too high clock speed)

Comment: While working with windows it also occurs, but rather seldom - on Ubuntu it's quite often.
Laptop is not really new - couple of years so no warranty but this might be a good point - thanks!

Comment: my graphics card is also from that era, can't oc anymore to 1500mhz...

Comment: might be an obvious question but what do you mean with OC?

Comment: OverClock. Used a lot on r/overclocking